# loading image into view after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.1

Here is the problem I ran into just now. I have a chat function part of my laravel application that loads respective users images as they type in the conversation. What I cannot figure out is when I append the url for the profile picture into the view, it will not actually display the picture, it just shows a "placeholder" of where the picture should be.

I know the code works for a fact because I can see in the console log the correct path for the picture inside the assets folder.

So my question is how would I display a picture after retrieving info from an ajax call.

```
$('.chat-wrapper').append(
                    "<div class='message " + sent + "'>" +
                    "<div class='media-left'>" +
                    "<a href=''><img scr=" + data.profilePicture + " class='img-circle img-50x50' title=''></a>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "<div class='media-body'>" +
                    "<small class='small-gray p-l-10 pull-right'>" + data.time + "</small>"+
                    "<div class='heading'>" +
                    "<span>"+data.authorUserName+"</span>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "<p>" + messageText + "</p>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "</div>"
            );
```

Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: sounds like the image name/path is incorrect/out of context

Comment: I want to make sure I understand that. You have console.log(data.profilePicture) and it gives the correct URL, but the image does not appear. What happens if you inspect the code? Does it show <img scr="undefined" class='img-circle img-50x50' title=''>? Or, does it show the proper path??

Comment: Can you show us your ajax call and when it's called?  do you have this append inside of your `success`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.chat-wrapper').append(
                "<div class='message " + sent + "'>" +
                "<div class='media-left'>" +
                "<a href=''><img src='" + data.profilePicture + "' class='img-circle img-50x50' title=''></a>" +
                "</div>" +
                "<div class='media-body'>" +
                "<small class='small-gray p-l-10 pull-right'>" + data.time + "</small>"+
                "<div class='heading'>" +
                "<span>"+data.authorUserName+"</span>" +
                "</div>" +
                "<p>" + messageText + "</p>" +
                "</div>" +
                "</div>"
        );
```

src isn't spelt correctly, then notice the quotes after the src and the end of src also, try this out.

Comment: Youre the man!! Worked like a charm. I don't know how I missed that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused when you're in a route that does not represent the base URL properly.

You can use the asset() helper function to build the URL to your asset folder relative to the public directory on your server.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-asset